# Wget in Android terminal

Tags: android, linux, root

How can I use wget command in "Android Terminal Emulator" app in android. It says /system/bin/sh: wget: not found. It means need to install wget in android. Please help me.

Comment: have you try any wget install command ?

Comment: related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/185217/how-to-get-wget-on-my-non-rooted-android-device

Answer (score 6):

You need to install [busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) in your android system then you can execute wget command,try to get it from play store

```
root@android:/ # busybox wget
```

Comment: You can also copy the binary from the busybox website https://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/

Answer (score 2):

There's no wget binary in Android, you are expected to get that information from error message. So you need to install wget first. 
Try using this link: https://jacob.hoffman-andrews.com/android/wget/

Answer (score 0):

At least on Lollipop for me (possibly earlier?) there's [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html), an alternative to wget for many cases.

Comment: `curl` is not present on 8.1.0_r60 unfortunately.